# default selected first option values

Tags: javascript, java

I want to select first option of my select list default on ready and want to get the id and value of that selected option  i am using code below

```
<s:select disabled="%{readOnly}" name="rigName" id="rigId"
                        value="%{#attr.resultTable.rigName}" list="rigItemsList" headerValue="Select Rig" headerKey="-1"
                        listKey="rigId" listValue="rigName"  />
```

this is displaying perfectly list and on change is also working fine.But when i am trying to select default first option and get value not able to get 
thanks in advance

```
var firstvalue = $("#rigId option:first").attr('selected','selected');
var option = $('option:selected', this).attr('rigId ');
alert(option);
```

undefined! message is showing

Comment: `undefined!` on WHAT?  Please be more specific

Comment: what do you wnat to do with var option = $('option:selected', this).attr('rigId '); ?

Comment: I want to get get first default selected options id and value to pass in my function ,from the above  i am trying to get the id but the id value is giving as undefined.

Comment: showing 1 page in default i need the first option selected from the selectbox where i need id and value to pass in my calling function .thanks in advance